# Needing conformation box before delete in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am needing a conformation box to appear before cells are deleted.
Thank you for all the great help. In advance.

Here is script

```
function clearRange() {
    //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LOAD ASSIGNMENT');
    sheet.getRange('B7:G7').clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your script!

Here's documentation on how to do that:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set

Comment: Thank you for that information, when I inserted that is has an error.  Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context. (line 1, file "CLEAR")
Dismiss.

Comment: GOOGLE SHEETS SPREADSHEET

Comment: function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LOAD ASSIGNMENT');
  sheet.getRange('B7:G7').clearContent();
}

Comment: I got it I change it to spreadsheet app instead and it works great.  Thank you so very much. You are the best!!!!!

Comment: If this solved feel free to mark the answer, below the down arrow.

Comment: Did I put it in the wrong spot.. it's before my clear script?   thanks